# PyQwt 5.x w/ PyQt 4.6 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, qt, qwt

Looking for Qt 4.6 features but it seems PyQwt 5.x is bundled only with PyQt.  Compiling from source looks a bit daunting, any ideas on how I might get PyQwt to operate with Qt 4.6+?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question.

PyQwt 5.x needs PyQt to work. If you want PyQwt without Python, then you are searching for "qwt" which is specifically for Qt 4.7+.

If you need a compiled version of PyQwt 5.x and want to use it with PyQt 4.9.x and e.g. Python 2.7, then you might have a look at [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqwt)
There you can find precompiled Python extensions for Windows for different python versions.

In this case PyQwt 5.x with PyQt 4.7 (or higher) and precompiled binary from the page above is working for me.